# Writing a simple loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops, output

Hey so I'm writing a program where, the user inputs exactly 10 words, and the computer outputs each word that has an `A` or `a` in it. I wrote the program with some help and now I need to now how how make it where the user can input 10 words back to back with a while loop. Here is what I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadASH{ 
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        String name;
        String S="";
        System.out.println("Please enter any word.");
        S = in.nextLine();
        if(S.contains("a")||S.contains("A"))
          System.out.println(S);
        else System.out.println("The word you entered contains no a's or A's");
    }
}
```

Comment: Learn how to use your debugger.

Comment: where is your loop? Make a `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)`

Comment: What is the exact problem you're facing? Sometimes posing the question can help you find the answer!

Comment: @nachokk where exaxtly in the code do i add the loop? Also I think its suppose to be a while not a for. But if its not possible with a while for is fine.

Comment: @Meesh My question is how and where do I add the loop so the user can enter 10 words.

Comment: It's the same using `while` or `for`, for is more clear..`int i=0; while(i++ < 10){ ..//code here }`

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually have a loop, something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class ReadASH{ 
   public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name;
    String S;
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
      System.out.println("Please enter any word.");
      S = in.nextLine();
      if (S.contains("a")||S.contains("A"))
        System.out.println(S);
      else System.out.println("The word you entered contains no a's or A's");
    }
  }
}
```

Updated code based on comment:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class ReadASH{ 
   public static void main(String[] args){
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String name;
    int wordsToRead = 10;
    String words[] = new String[wordsToRead];

    for (int i=0; i< wordsToRead; i++) {
      System.out.println("Please enter any word.");
      words[i] = in.nextLine();
    }
    for (int i=0; i< wordsToRead; i++) {
      if (words[i].contains("a")||words[i].contains("A"))
        System.out.println(words[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot, but I was wondering is it possible to write it where the user enters all ten words first and then the comptuer outputs then back. (ex the user input "basketball, ball, door, racecar,apple, Ant, exact, wet, dont, like" and then the computer outputs "basketball, racecar,ball,appple,Ant"

Comment: @ShadonHamedani You want to store your results in an array, and then loop over that array.

Comment: It looks great but now when i try to run it i get an error saying 
"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at HWReadASH.main(HWReadASH.java:13)"

Comment: @ShadonHamedani Mea Culpa!! The index lookups should be using the loop index!

Comment: So how exactly do we go about it fixing it?

Comment: @ShadonHamedani If you look at the code, I have already fixed the same code.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly now, Last thing If I would want to make the program so it only outputs words that contain two or more a's how would the code change?

Comment: @ShadonHamedani then you should look at using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String) instead of the two contains. I will leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Alright well thanks for all your help anyways!